# MySQL manual change tracking

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, change-tracking

I am trying to implement a database change control using MySQL. To control inserts and updates I want to use something similar to a TIMESTAMP field in SQLServer (A column that autoincrements when a insert/update is made over a row). Does exists something similar in MySQL? If a want to do it with MySQL my only way is write a trigger for update and another to insert in every table of the database?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can create your columns like this

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

The `created_at` field is set on insert and the `updated_at` field is automatically updated on update.

[Docs are here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Comment: It seems like a implicit trigger on the table creation. Thanks a lot.